# @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq CircleCI issue, timed out

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, circleci

I am creating a microservice in NestJS. Now I want to use RabbitMQ to send messages to another service.

I created the functionality and it works perfectly fine. But the problem comes up when I want to merge it and the CircleCI test is running. After 10 minutes I get the message:
`Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded`

This happens only on the service with the producer. The consuming service works fine.

Can someone explain why this happens and how I can fix this?

RabbitMQ is imported in the GraphQLModule below.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLFederationModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    }),
    DatabaseModule,
    AuthModule,
    RabbitmqModule,
  ],
  providers: [UserResolver, FamilyResolver, AuthResolver],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

RabbitmqModule:

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { RabbitMQModule } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';
import { UserProducer } from './producers/user.producer';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    RabbitMQModule.forRootAsync(RabbitMQModule, {
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        exchanges: [
          {
            name: config.get('rabbitMQ.exchange'),
            type: config.get('rabbitMQ.exchangeType'),
          },
        ],
        uri: config.get('rabbitMQ.url'),
        connectionInitOptions: { wait: false },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [UserProducer],
  exports: [UserProducer],
})
export class RabbitmqModule {}
```

The CircleCI output:
[image]

UPDATE:

It crashes when it starts seeding the database. It seeds the database correctly but when it is done, it doesn't stop the app. This happens on my PC too, not only in CircleCi.

The following script is called:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

import { SeedService } from '../src/database/service/seed.service';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app/app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);

  try {
    await app.get(SeedService).seed();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  } finally {
    await app.close();
  }
}

bootstrap();
```

But this doesn't close the app correctly. When I log before and after `await app.close()` it logs both.

Comment: What version of `@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq` are you using right now?

Comment: `"@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq": "^1.15.2"`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing a little bit more about your scenario. What is it that the task in Circle CI is trying to accomplish? From the screenshot it looks like you may be attempting to use this script to apply database migrations?

If you boot up the entire microservice like this it's going to hold the process open waiting for potential messages to come through. Are you calling `app.close()` anywhere in your script? You will need to terminate the process appropriately once your script is completed or refactor this to not require booting up the whole service like this